# Why is self-attention used for image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, transformers

I'm wondering why you would use Self-Attention across an entire image for image classification. What are the advantages of Self-Attention compared to a pure MLP?

Comment: What do you mean by "a pure MLP"? Feeding directly the pixel RGB values to a MLP with a huge input layer?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. But I am assuming that the self-attention is across the entire image not just over patches.

Comment: Self attention with pixels would lead to huge memory costs, because it scales $\mathcal O (N^2)$